# How do I make such a Toolbar - drop-down menu, as in the image?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a menu like the one in image-2. Here is the code on the toolbar, but I can't create the drop-down menu as in the picture.

[This is Toolbar. Image-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fex0L.png)
[Drop-down menu. Image-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmZ2k.png)

Image-1 Code Example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x400")

# Create Toolbar
# Toolbar images
img1 = tk.PhotoImage(file = r"D:\Code\img1.gif")
img2 = tk.PhotoImage(file = r"D:\Code\img1.gif")
img3 = tk.PhotoImage(file = r"D:\Code\img1.gif")

toolbar = tk.Frame(root, bd=1, relief=RAISED) 
toolbar.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)

menubtn1 = tk.Menubutton(toolbar, relief=FLAT, compound= LEFT, 
text="",image=img1)
menubtn1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=0, pady=0)

menubtn2 = tk.Menubutton(toolbar, relief=FLAT, compound= LEFT, 
text="", image=img2)
menubtn2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=0, pady=0)

menubtn3 = tk.Menubutton(toolbar, relief=FLAT, compound= LEFT, 
text="", image=img3)
menubtn3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=0, pady=0)

# drop down menubtn1
menu = tk.Menu(menubtn1, tearoff=0)
menubtn1.config(menu=menu)

menu.insert_command(0, label='Submit', command=lambda: 
print('Submit clicked'))
imgvar1 = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'D:\Code\img1.gif') 
menu.insert_cascade(1, image=imgvar1, command=lambda: print('Im pop out clicked'))

imgvar2 = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'D:\Code\img1.gif')
menu.insert_cascade(2, image=imgvar2, command=lambda: print('Im pop out clicked'))

imgvar3 = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'D:\Code\img1.gif')
menu.insert_cascade(3, image=imgvar3, command=lambda: print('Im pop out clicked'))

imgvar4 = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'D:\Code\img1.gif')
menu.insert_cascade(4, image=imgvar4, command=lambda: print('Im pop out clicked'))
menu.insert_separator(4)

imgvar5 = tk.PhotoImage(file=r'D:\Code\img1.gif')
menu.insert_cascade(5, image=imgvar5, command=lambda: print('Im pop out clicked'))

root.mainloop()
```

A drop-down menu is obtained, but with only one image per button. Is there a way to group four or five image buttons in a row?
Can anybody help me?

Comment: probably you will have to create own system using Frame or window Toplevel. And you will have to add all code which opens and closes it.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a [mcve] that uses text instead of images? Since we don't have your images it's difficult to run your code.

Comment: When you say _"like the one in image-2"_  do you mean that you want the dropdown to have multiple rows and multiple columns? If so, do some research on the `columnbreak` option. It allows you to have multiple columns on every platform except OSX.

Comment: Yes. I want the drop-down menu to have a few rows and a few columns. I will now search for the "columnbreak option".
Thanks for the advice.